# Как запаковать проект, использующий jar-библиотеку

Tags: java, jar, javac

Есть проект, который запускается командой `java -cp ".:lib.jar" Main`. Как его запокавать в jar (не распаковывая lib.jar), чтобы этот jar файл можно было выполнить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этих целей, можно попробовать [one-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/), присутствует плагин под `maven` и `ant`.

Если не хотите использовать сторонние решения, то можно попытаться самому реализовать `ClassLoader`, который будет уметь подгружать классы из внутренних jar архивов.

Comment: Как вообще происходит сборка в jar в реальных проектах, которые используют много разных библиотек?

Comment: Подключают зависимости через программу сборки, потом ею собирают  jar. В итогом  в артефакте уже содержатся те классы, которые необходимы программе.

Comment: Они там содержатся распакованные или в jar?

Comment: в распакованном виде. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html             ...